# Prototype UITableViewCell is not at top of UITableView in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

As the questions already says: When I add a prototype UITableViewCell to my TableView, the cell is not displayed at the top, here is a image:
[image]

How can I get the cell to the top of my TableView again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that your trackViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets == YES, so additional topInset of 64px will be added to first UIScrollView in its view (this is UITableView in your case).

You can do the following:

Set table view origin y to 0

or

set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO.

Comment: can I find .automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets in Storyboard/Interface builder or do I have to set this in code?

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard select **viewcontroller** (the yellow circle with a white square inside) then click on extend edges under bottom bars option.

[image: ViewController]

Remember to select your view controller not your tableview or tableviewcell.