# UITableView in Storyboard hidden first cell when it back it will OK ? why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`, when I start the app, first cell is hidden but when I navigate and come back it's visble. Anyone has any idea ?

Comment: it   -64  in Y place   hidded  back sceen ,  I   try  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379567/prototype-uitableviewcell-is-not-at-top-of-uitableview-in-storyboard   method , but  it not OK ?

Comment: If your app have Navigation bar and status visible , just add them to your storyboard scenes.

Comment: i want  more details @GokerGe

Comment: TableViewController in Storyboard, the nav   cover  tableview  just   64 point screen , when I  push  next Tableviewcontroller and  back it become OK ,  it  just happen  when i first star the app demo! 
I  have find  the wrong  with  my demo, but it have another wrong  happen, the nav  become  grey colour

Comment: I  have  commit this  demo in  github (https://github.com/StevenGardnerGMJ/DustStarstoryboard)  click the button (学科)  you will find  the problem in demo .

Answer (score 0):

when use storyboard -> tab bar controller,  the right view have a button "under top bar" so cancel it,you will find it work OK !
2015-08-28 13:53:28  I  have  solve this  problem,  anyone who have the same question,  just see my demo

Comment: IF you do this  the nav change  to gray, it seem something is cover on it